# how to add labels to files in producing multiple plots code

Tags: r

I have the following code that produces multiple plots, each in a separate pdf file

```
myplot <-function(ind,dfList) {
 dat <- dfList[[ind]]
  detects <- as.numeric(dat$Result2[dat$cens== 0])
  pdf(file=paste("Desktop/qqplot_",ind,".pdf",sep = ""))
  qqnorm(log(detects), ylab="Ln of uncensored data in ppm", main="Q-Q plot", pch=16) 
  qqline(log(detects))
             dev.off()
           }

Plots <- lapply(1:3, myplot , dfList = mydata)
```

Question 1:  This code produces 3 pdf files.  The files' labels are 1, 2, and 3.  How can insert a code that would relabel each file as plot X, plot Y, plot Z.

Question 2:  In my myplot function, the plot's title is Q-Q plot but I would like to change the title correspond to the names of the file.  So each plot title should be plot X, plot Y, plot Z.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible because you did not provide any data. Based on the code (that does not run), it looks like the files will be names `qqplot_1`, `qqplot_2`, etc. You need to adjust your line of code where you start with `pdf(...`. Secondly, you can adjust the title of the plot using the `main="Whatever you want to say here"` argument as referenced above. You'll probably need to use `paste()` as you did in the line above to reference a variable / column value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested due to no dummy data, but should work.

```
myplot <- function(ind,dfList) {
    # Add a vector of labels
    # then use index at will to build plot and title strings etc
    labels <- c("X", "Y", "Z")
    myfilename <- paste("Desktop/qqplot_",labels[ind],".pdf",sep = "")
    mytitle <- paste("Plot ",labels[ind],sep = "")

    dat <- dfList[[ind]]
    detects <- as.numeric(dat$Result2[dat$cens== 0])
    pdf(file=myfilename)
        qqnorm(log(detects), ylab="Ln of uncensored data in ppm", main=mytitle, pch=16) 
        qqline(log(detects))
    dev.off()
}

Plots <- lapply(1:3, myplot , dfList = mydata)
```

Comment: Looks like it should work. Also untested would be to try  `,title=bquote(Plot~.( c("X", "Y", "Z")[ind])),`